# Ngrx change counter state not working how can I make it work?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a state that looks like this:

```
const initialState: AppState = {
    productsList: [],
    counter: 1
};
```

On click of a button, I want to increment the counter by 1.

This is my reducer:

```
const _stateReducer = createReducer(
initialState,
on(updateProductCounterId, state=>{
debugger
return {
  ...state,
  counter: state.counter + 1
    }
 })
);
```

Action looks like this:

```
export const updateProductCounterId = createAction(
"[Product] Update Counter Id"
);
```

But on the reducer, when I'm trying to return the new state :

```
return {
  ...state,
  counter: state.counter + 1
    }
```

It does not recognize `state.counter`, only `state.productsList`.

What I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Try `counter: state['counter'] + 1` and lets see if it works

Comment: Can you post your `AppState` interface?